# Drupal- load a node in a Lightbox?

Tags: drupal, lightbox, lightbox2

How should I load a node in a lightbox?

I managed with this:

```
<a href="mysite.com/node/59/lightbox2" rel="lightframe[|width:751px; height:500px;]">Size Dimensions</a>
```

But I need to theme the lightbox and when I copy page-node-lightbox2.tpl.php to my theme folder then all the lightbox shows is the text:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
```

Its not a big problem for me, but my solution only works if the node id is in the url, I cant use the url shortcut instead. This makes me think their must be a better way to do it, but I cant find documentation that works for me anywhere.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Very nice solution will be using modules [contextphp](https://drupal.org/project/contextphp), [delta](https://drupal.org/project/delta) + [omega theme](https://drupal.org/project/omega) 3.x

Contextphp condirions code:

```
return $_GET['format'] == 'simple';
```